# Adding class="active" to parent when child is the current item selected

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

This is what's happening in my boostrap menu. When I click any item in the dropdown the child is selected (`class="active"`) but the parent is not. So, if the dropdown is closed you can't see in the menu the selected page.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li class="my-class"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Brokerage</a></li>
      <li class="my-other-class"><a href="#">Consulting</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="my-class"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to do it with this but it's not working:

```
$('li').click(function() {
 $(this).parents().addClass('.active');  
});
```

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.It's worth pointing out the the parent of the li is the ul...not the li holding the dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

You have some mistakes in your jQuery:

```
$('li').click(function() {
   $(this).parent().addClass('active');  
});
```

1.) It is `parent()` in your case, not `parents()`.

2.) `addClass('active')`is correct, not `addClass('.active')`.

[Bootply Example](http://www.bootply.com/120142)

Comment: +1 for being 15 seconds faster than me. ;) But you still got the 'period' bug in you Bootply Example.

Comment: ha, you are correct! Somehow my fork didn't apply the change. Thanks for pointing it out, I corrected it and thanks for the +1 :)

Comment: @Sebsemillia In your Bootply 'Brokerage' (under Services) is highlighted but 'Services' is not and that is what I'm trying to do. Thanks.

Comment: Try this: http://www.bootply.com/120146. I changed your jQuery and added the nav element in your HTML, which Bootstrap needs.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't put the `.` in the class name you pass to `addClass`. Also, `parents()` selects all its ancestors. If you just want the direct parent, use `parent()` (without 's').

```
 $(this).parent().addClass('active');
```